# How to make a full-width background option in visual composer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using X-Theme with Visual Composer 4.6.2 and I'm trying to create a divider layer that goes the full width of the screen like in this mock-up (the blue bar in between the content):
[image: mockup]

However, all that VC will let me do is go as wide as its container. I've used this on other, pre-fab themes before, but I don't know how to do this. I tried using revslider and a regular img, but neither work. Any ideas?

[This is the dev site this is currently on.](http://smartip2016.wpengine.com/phone-systems/)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Check Your Page Template  (right side of page - Page attribute -> Template)**

if its not full width then its not possible

**so set page template as full width**  and it will surly work

OR THIS IF step 1 is not working

Edit page section ->

ROW Settings -> General -> Content Type

set content type as full width.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the edit page of your home.
Look for the line you want to edit.
Click on edit -> Row type -> "full width"